# Nodatime Parsing Instant with InstantPattern fails

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

I use  NodaTime, Version=2.2.3.0
I have set up a patter to match various Instant patterns
The last pattern should match the examples below.

```
IPattern<Instant> pattern = new CompositePatternBuilder<Instant>
{
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFF") , _ => true },
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFF") , _ => false },
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dd'-'MM'-'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFF") , _ => false },
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFF") , _ => false },
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("M'/'dd'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFF") , _ => false },
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFF") , _ => false },
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("M.d.yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFF") , _ => false },
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dd.MM.yyyy HH':'mm':'ss.FFFFFFF") , _ => false },
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("M'/'d'/'yyyy H':'mm':'ss tt") , _ => false },
    { InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("M'/'d'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss tt") , _ => false },
}
.Build();
```

I can parse the two first of

1. "9/28/2017 10:55:49 AM"
2. "9/22/2017 12:02:53 PM"
3. "1/11/2018 12:25:59 AM"

But not the 3rd one. Why ?

error message indicates "^1/11/2018 12:25:59 AM" error at the first position of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think you actually need that many patterns - I suspect you don't need both `M` and `MM` versions, for example.

But the problem is that you're using `HH` with `tt`. `HH` means "24-hour clock", so a value of 12 means 12pm... but then your value specifies that it's AM.

If you look at the exception message, it tries to make that clear:

> Unhandled Exception: NodaTime.Text.UnparsableValueException: The individual values for the fields 'H' and 't' created an inconsistency in the NodaTime.LocalTime type. Value being parsed: '1/11/2018 12:25:59 AM'.

Basically, you should use `h` instead:

```
var pattern = InstantPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt");
```

(Note that you don't need to escape `/` and `:` - while they are culture-sensitive, you're using the invariant culture which uses values of `/` and `:` anyway, so it's simpler just to leave them unescaped. `-` has no special meaning in an `InstantPattern`, so that doesn't need escaping either.)

The reason your first two values don't fail is that in those cases the 24-hour hour-of-day that's specified matches the AM/PM designation. "10" is in AM, and "12" is in PM.

Comment: Yes thats it. Thx alot. I'm going to clean up database records and make sure all read and write in iso format. Then I will get rid of all the patterns.